# I can mean equity, what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I can mean equity, 
> I am part of justice.
>  fish have my odds.
>   my evens is a greek god.

what am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you

> Fairness

I can mean equity,

> Fairness means equity

I am part of justice.

> Justice brings fairness.

fish have my odds.

> **F**a**i**r**n**e**s**s > [Fins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_fin)

my evens is a greek god.

> F**a**i**r**n**e**s**s** > [Ares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares)

Comment: For `fish have my odds` you can take the final odd letter as well

Comment: D***, I thought it was going to be scales ...

Comment: @WillCrawford - quite true - seeing justice and fish, I too thought of scales, and as I struggled with the other clues ran posted his answer!